# RAdwords error ("server certificate verification failed")

Tags: r, google-ads-api

When I run the following code involving the RAdwords package, I get an error which seems to be related to certificates. Is there a simple solution to this?

```
library(RAdwords)
google_auth <- doAuth()
```

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    server certificate
>   verification failed. CAfile:
>   /home/pavel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt
>   CRLfile: none

The error occurs on Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.2.0, RCurl 1.95-4.5, and RAdwords 0.1.4.

Comment: Could you provide any information about your operating system, R version and RAdwords package version? The lastest version of the package supports Adwords API version v201502 and v201409. The tag v201402 might not be adequat.

Comment: Maybe an update of the RCurl package helps.

Comment: @Johannes I added information about the package and R versions. Basically, everything is up to date. I guess I'll wait for an update and hope it works then. :)

Comment: @bodyfarmer Thanks for the help with the formatting.

Comment: Why do you have two Stack Overflow accounts with the same name - Pavel Logacev and Pavel? You just edited your post with your other account and added new server error information, and you are responding to comments with it too.

Comment: The SSL certificate 'ca-bindle.crt' might be missing on your system. What do get with:
system.file("CurlSSL", "ca-bundle.crt", package = "RCurl")

Comment: @Johannes The file is not missing. However, changing line 51 in getAuth.R from "RCurl::getURL(url, cainfo=cert)" to "RCurl::getURL(url)" seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Pavel Depending on the OS, the handling of Curl SSL certificates is different. In previous RAdwords version I used `RCurl::getURL(url)` which works fine on Ubuntu 12.04 an iOS. However on Windows the certificate cannot be located. Hence I load the certificate manually:
`cert <- system.file("CurlSSL", "ca-bundle.crt", package = "RCurl")` #SSL Certificate Fix for Windows  
`RCurl::getURL(url, cainfo=cert)`
We have to figure out why this does not hold on Ubuntu 14.04. We should find a solution which works on any OS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04, but manually downloading (and overriding the `RCurl` shipped version of) the `cacert.pem` from the [cURL homepage](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) resolved the issue. I know it's an ugly workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Try testing whether RCurl is working for any https URL.

```
getURL("https://stat.ethz.ch")
```

If it's not working then most likely you need to install the curl-dev package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

And then reinstall RCurl:

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

The [FAQ for RCurl](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html) was helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding RCurl shiped ca-bundle.crt with latest from curl works for me.

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt"
```

In your case:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O "/home/pavel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt"
```