# Issue with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: r, centos6, google-ads-api

I using the library `Radwords` to acccess adwords API through R script.

I have my client-id and client secret from google developer console but I see we do not 'enable' google Adwords API through console like we do otherwise? Anyway I got my client Id and client secret from there.
Besides, have my developer token for the test MCC account and have applied for the basic access. Until then I am trying to continue with developer test token.

But at `doAuth()` function, I enter my client id and client secret from google console project and deveoper token from adwords account, but I get an error :

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I found this link [RAdwords error ("server certificate verification failed")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806412/radwords-error-server-certificate-verification-failed) and installed Rcurl but that did not help either

I am on a server with CentOS.

Comment: Did you forget to post error message?

Comment: @Orions: Oh, yes I did. UPdated

Comment: Here you will find a detailed instruction for the authentication with RAdwords and the Adwords API: http://jburkhardt.github.io/RAdwords/auth/
You write something about test account. Adwords API access will not work with AdWords test accounts. Read more about the requirements for using RAdwords here: http://jburkhardt.github.io/RAdwords/requirements/